# Binary tree adding nodes only in left. How can I make it work both on left and right of the root node?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I recently started learning Data structures and Algorithm. I am creating a binary tree which is adding nodes only on the left of tree. How can I create in such a way that it should add nodes on both the sides of the root node and look like this:

```
         2               
        / \       
       /   \      
      /     \     
     /       \    
     7       5       
    / \     / \   
   /   \   /   \  
   2   6   3   6
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
public class BinaryTreeOperations {

    BinaryTreeNode root;

    //let's start with an empty binary tree
    public BinaryTreeOperations(){
        root = null;
    }

    //let's initialize our tree with a root node
    public BinaryTreeOperations(BinaryTreeNode rootNode){
        this.root = rootNode;
    }


    public void insert(int data)
    {
        root = insertNode(root, data);
    }




    private BinaryTreeNode insertNode(BinaryTreeNode node, int data){


        //To check if the root is null then create a root node with no children
        if (node == null) {

            System.out.println("inserting root node"+ data+"\n");
            node = new BinaryTreeNode(data);
        }
        else {
            if(node.getRightChild() == null){
                System.out.println("inserting right child :"+data+"\n");
                node.rightChild=insertNode(node.rightChild, data);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("inserting left child :"+data+"\n");
                node.leftChild = insertNode(node.leftChild, data);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    public int countNodes() {
        return countNodes(root);
    }

    private int countNodes(BinaryTreeNode r) {
        if (r == null)
            return 0;
        else
        {
            int count = 1;
            count += countNodes(r.getLeftChild());
            count += countNodes(r.getRightChild());
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class BinaryTreeMain {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        BinaryTreeOperations binaryTreeOperations = new BinaryTreeOperations();
        binaryTreeOperations.insert(12);
        binaryTreeOperations.insert(17);
        binaryTreeOperations.insert(11);
        binaryTreeOperations.insert(21);
        binaryTreeOperations.insert(27);

        System.out.println("Total number of nodes :" + binaryTreeOperations.countNodes());

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the output? Can you show us your main if any?

Comment: Updated the question with a class with main function.

Comment: Did you implement BinaryTreeNode yourself?

Comment: You need a Ordering condition, that determines on which side the data should be stored. Now your condition is only `node.getRightChild() == null`. Option 1: order by `int data`, Option 2: order by balancing the height (left/right) of your tree

Comment: Read about AVL trees, you need to implement rotations to balance B trees

Comment: @Mad Matts I tried your suggestion but it's not working as I cannot come back to the root node once the height check is done.

Comment: @shikhar : I will try that

Answer (score 1):

You can for example store an extra information on each node, like a boolean that gives the direction where to insert, and you switch it after insertion.
It requires only few lines more than what you already did.